# Retrieve data from Mysql database, display on a form, and allow user to update using PHP

Tags: php, sql-update

I am VERY NEW to PHP.  I have a page where I want a user to be able to enter a citation and that information is then passed to a php script that queries against the database, returns the information in a form, and then allows the user to update any of the fields returned in that form.

I have three problems:

1)  When data returns, is only returns the first word in the field.  Many of the fields contains multiple words.

2)  When the users changes data in the field, the database isn't updated.

3)  I don't seem to know how to get the form fields to display like I do for data entry.

Here is the code that queries and returns the data for the user to review and update if necessary:

```
<?php  


mysql_connect("***************", "*********", "****") or die(mysql_error()); 
mysql_select_db("***********") or die(mysql_error()); 

$searchterm= $_POST['searchterm'];

$query = "SELECT Citation, Category, Overview, Facts, Decision, Keywords, Link     FROM     cases WHERE citation = '$searchterm'";

$result  = mysql_query($query);

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    echo "<form action=".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']." method=post>" .
         "Case Citation: <input type=text name=Citation value={$row['Citation'] }><br>" .
     "Category: <input type=text name=Category value={$row['Category'] }><br>" . 
     "Overview: <input type=text name=Overview value={$row['Overview'] }><br>" . 
     "Case Facts: <input type=text name=Facts value={$row['Facts'] }><br>" . 
     "Decision: <input type=text name=decision value={$row['Decision'] }><br>" . 
     "Keywords: <input type=text name=Keywords value={$row['Keywords'] }><br>" . 
     "Weblink: <input type=text name=Link value={$row['Link'] }><br>" . 
     "<input type=submit name=submit value=Update>" .
     "</form>";
} 

//when they click submit
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) { 

$Citation=$_POST['Citation'];
$Category=$_POST['Category'];
$Overview=$_POST['Overview'];
$Facts=$_POST['Facts'];
$Decision=$_POST['Decision'];
$Keywords=$_POST['Keywords'];
$Link=$_POST['Link'];

$update = "UPDATE IGNORE cases SET citation='$citation', category='$category', overview='$overview', facts='$facts', decision='$decision', keywords='$keywords', link='$link' WHERE citation = '%$searchterm%'";
$add = mysql_query($update);

} 
  ?>
```

Here is the form I use to add data:

```
<form action="process.php" method="post"> 
Case Citation: <input type="text" name="citation" size=128><br> 
Category: <input type="text" name = "category" size=56><br> 
Overview: <textarea class="textarea" cols="96" row="8" name = "overview"> </textarea><br> 
Case Facts:  <textarea class="textarea" cols="96" row="8" name = "facts"></textarea><br>
Decision:  <input type="text" name = "decision" size=56><br>
Keywords: <textarea class="textarea" cols="96" row="8" name = "keywords"></textarea><br>
Web Link: <input type="text" name = "link" size=128><br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit"> 
</form>
```

And this is the code that saves the information to the database:

```
<? 
  $citation=$_POST['citation']; 
  $category=$_POST['category']; 
  $overview=$_POST['overview']; 
  $facts=$_POST['facts']; 
  $decision=$_POST['decision']; 
  $keywords=$_POST['keywords']; 
  $link=$_POST['link']; 
  mysql_connect("*************", "************", "*********") or die(mysql_error()); 
  mysql_select_db("************") or die(mysql_error()); 
  mysql_query("INSERT INTO `cases` VALUES ('$citation', '$category', '$overview', '$facts', '$decision', '$keywords', '$link')"); 
  Print "Your information has been successfully added to the database.  Add case page will automatically reload."; 

?>
```

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: You have `name=Facts` and `value={$row['Overview'] }`. Attributes values must be enclosed with`"`

Comment: You should do a `$result  = mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_error());`

Answer (score 0):

Your first (and probably the rest...) problem is caused by how you are building your form:

```
echo "<form action=".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']." method=post>" .
     "Case Citation: <input type=text name=Citation value={$row['Citation'] }><br>" .
 "Category: <input type=text name=Category value={$row['Category'] }><br>" . 
 "Overview: <input type=text name=Overview value={$row['Overview'] }><br>" . 
 "Case Facts: <input type=text name=Facts value={$row['Facts'] }><br>" . 
 "Decision: <input type=text name=decision value={$row['Decision'] }><br>" . 
 "Keywords: <input type=text name=Keywords value={$row['Keywords'] }><br>" . 
 "Weblink: <input type=text name=Link value={$row['Link'] }><br>" . 
 "<input type=submit name=submit value=Update>" .
 "</form>";
```

Note that the values of all attributes are unquoted, so in html one of you inputs could look like:

```
Decision: <input type=text name=decision value=this is some text from that field><br>
```

and that is not valid html.

You should quote all values and prepare / escape them for use in html:

```
 'Decision: <input type=text name=decision value="' . htmlspecialchars($row['Decision']) . '"><br>' . 
 etc.
```

Apart from that you have a sql injection problem that you should solve by switching to PDO (or mysqli) and prepared statements with bound variables.

Note that a sql injection problem not only puts you at risk but it also invalidates your sql easily if one of your values contains for example a `'` character.

Comment: So I updated the respective rows to read:  'Case Citation: <input type=text name=Citation value="' . htmlspecialchars($row['Citation']) . '"><br>' .   and now get Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'Link' (T_STRING), expecting ',' or ';' in /home/u930515875/public_html/protected/vanducases.php on line 55

Comment: @Brian K Buttrey I used single and double quotes to make it easily readable, you should adapt the quotes to go with your code. You can escape double quotes in your double-quoted string like `\"` if you want to.

Answer (score 0):

In the while loop check value={$row['Citation'] }.

Your database field name first letter is capital ?

Check database field name again.